# Null reference Exception unhandled by the user code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I build my solution in visual studio(successfull) and I am trying to run it  but for some reason at the following line of code it was throwing  the exception I went several articles but there was no exact solution how this could be handled

```
public static int GetCurrentPolicyClassId()
    {
        **int policyClassId = (int) HttpContext.Current.Session[AppConstants.SK_POLICYCLASSID];**
        return policyClassId;
    }
```

Comment: Something is null there... put a breakpoint over that line, then you can Watch what's going on with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the values in the chain you've called is null. You just need to check before getting the values:

```
if(HttpContext != null && 
   HttpContext.Current != null &&
   HttpContext.Current.Session != null &&
   HttpContext.Current.Session[AppConstants.SK_POLICYCLASSID] != null)
{
    // Get the value here.
}
else
{
    // Something was null. Either set a default value or throw an Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check if `HttpContext != null && HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null`

Answer (score 0):

any exception is handled by `try/catch` (or `finally`), if that exception is possible to handle in general.

For example `StackOverflowException` could not be handled.

You need to:

- what type of exception is
- understand reasons of it
- based on this decide if that exception is an *exceptional behaviour* in your application
- if yes, handle it with `try/catch` if program needs to handle it, or leav program to fail, as the exception recieved is too dangerous and it's better to let to fail everything.
- if this is not exceptional behavior, try to handle it with, for example null checks, or whatever...

Hope this helps.